# Azure - Access to blob with firewall restriction

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I'm new to the Azure environment, I need to give access to the Blob and File Share of a Container in the Storage Account of a project.
In the Networking settings of my Storage Account I have, Public Network access: "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses"
I have some Virtual Networks configured, and I have 2 ips configured (which are not from my computer).
At this moment I don't have access to Blob and File Share through the portal, only through "Microsoft Azure Storage Explore".
I want to know if with these rules, I can configure something else, (maybe AD DS) to have access to Blobls and File Share through the portal.

Thanks.

I tried to add Read permission to my Container IAM account, but I am already admin

Answer (score 0):

When Azure Storage is configured with Network Security set to "Enable from selected VNET or IP Address", you need to be coming in from secured machine (Either within VNET by correct NSGs or thru Public IP Address). In case you are behind firewall/gateway/proxy then Gateway's Public IP Address needs to be added to Network Config of Azure Storage Account.

Here is more info on Network Config of Storage Accounts - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal